# How to return List from Java 16 Stream.map()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, java-16

I am iterating over a list, calling `dynamoDBMapper.query()` which return a `PaginatedQueryList`.

```
public List<Person> getPerson(final List<UUID> personIds) {
        return personIds.stream().map(personId ->  dynamoDBMapper.query(Person.class, findByPersonId(personId)).stream()
            .map(Person::getPerson))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

I need to return List but the error I am getting is :

```
Required type:
List<Person>
Provided:
List<Stream<Person>>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Person` has a method `getPerson` which returns a `Person`?

Comment: Yes, this returns a person

Comment: Apparently, you need `return personIds.stream() .flatMap(personId ->  dynamoDBMapper.query(Person.class, findByPersonId(personId)).stream()) .map(Person::getPerson) .toList();` But it looks weird to have a `query` method returning a `List`, to be used for a single item. Isn’t there a variant like `dynamoDBMapper.query(Person.class, findByPersonIds(personIds))` returning the list of all persons in the first place?

Comment: `dynamoDBMapper.query(Person.class, findByPersonIds(personIds))` returns `PaginatedQueryList` which is a type of List only.

Comment: “which is a type of List only”—isn’t your task to get a type of List? For most environments, performing a single query will be more efficient than multiple queries, so even if you have to do post-processing like `dynamoDBMapper.query(Person.class, findByPersonIds(personIds)) .stream() .map(Person::getPerson) .toList()`, it’s preferable.

Answer (score 0):

This a a quote from javadoc for class [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

```
// Accumulate names into a List
     List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just few clarifying questions: what does method `Person::getPerson` return? is it instance of a class `Person` (that what I would expect for your code to work properly) or is it a `Stream`? Also in your code what does method `toList()` do?

Comment: `Person::getPerson` return a Person. You are correct. And I am using java 16 so no need of `Collector.toList()`, can directly do `toList()`. I'll update the question.